# How do I block/disable the images in a chat room?

Tags: support, chat, firefox

Can I easily block the images/gifs/embedded video media links in a StackExchange chat room without having to completely block everything globally in a browser?

The reason I had to ask this question because anyone can post one box images which are linked to a different site other than https://i.stack.imgur.com and I cannot find a way to block them using browser plug-ins since they are unrelated to https://chat.stackoverflow.com for example.

Comment: Do you want to block all the media links in a chat room, or just selective links? Do you happen to use Firefox?

Comment: @Firelord: All the media links displaying preview of media content in a chat room. Yes, I am using Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a userstyle:

```
.user-image, .ob-youtube { display: none; }
```

There is a [page with instructions on how to use userstyles](https://userstyles.org/help/stylish) that has directions for both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Will the major browsers load this image and merely not display it, or will they not load the image at all? Since the OP mentioned "sites other than imgur", merely hiding the image might not help them.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Uhh, I'm pretty sure they do (and JS would be required if you didn't want them to load at all), but don't quote me on that.

Comment: You can also answer [this](http://superuser.com/questions/895850/blocking-images-flash-gifs-on-specific-tab-in-firefox). (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259565/how-do-i-block-disable-the-images-in-a-chat-room#comment846117_259565)

Answer (score 2):

[Firelord](https://superuser.com/users/423702/firelord) asked this question
on
[superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/933496/how-to-block-all-cross-site-image-requests-originating-for-a-specific-website-in) 
and accepted as answer the
[imglikeopera](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imglikeopera/) plugin for firefox.